# Was the Ritva's teacher the Ba'al Hamaor's grandson?

Tags: history, rishonim

I came across this statement while learning [Ritva:](https://www.sefaria.org/Ritva_on_Sukkah.34b.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> והנכון כמו שפירש הרב בעל המאור ז״ל זקנו של רבינו נ״ר

Who is "Rabbeinu" that he refers to? To the best of my knowledge, his teacher the Rashba was not a descendant of the Baal Hamaor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the Ritva's teachers was Rav [Aharon Ha-Levi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharon_HaLevi), often known by the acronym רא"ה. He was indeed a direct descendant of the Ba'al Ha-Maor.

Comment: Notably they're both Levites https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7983313#7983313